# how to search similar entities in database using Example class from hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, search, entity, hibernate-search

i know that there are an Hibernate class called Example that we can use to get similar entities in order to do a search, but is it possible that this class permit to get entities searching in a generic way.

I explain, I build an example entity having a property called name with value = "myname", is Hibernate capable to return an entity which has property having value = "mname" ?

Comment: Search with hibernate like query. Is it a typo ?? `myname vs mname` ?

Comment: no not a typo, it is an example, the missed "y"  I did it on purpose. So no other solutions, I have to use the symbol '%' in my queries that is what you think, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's possible but to enable text-level similarity you need a Lucene index to speed-up the query, as it would otherwise be extremely inefficient to run on a relational database.

This is provided by [Hibernate Search](http://search.hibernate.org), the extension of Hibernate to integrate with Lucene and manage the indexes transparently.